# Integral Over Hypersurface Simplification

Tags: special-relativity

How does one see it as obvious that

$$\int_S \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^j} dS^{ji} = \int_S\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x^i} - \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^j})dS^{ij}$$

where $d S^{ij} = dx^i dx^{j*}   - dx^j dx^{i*} $

From [Landau's CToF](http://books.google.ie/books?id=X18PF4oKyrUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

It is clear from your definition that $dS^{ij}$ is an antisymmetric tensor: $dS^{ij}=-dS^{ji}$. Therefore, we can keep only the antisymmetric part of the two-tensor $B_{ij}\equiv \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^j}$. The symmetric part will give zero when multiplied by $dS^{ij}$. This immediately yields the equality you're looking for.

Alternatively, write out $B_{ij}S^{ij}=\frac{1}{2}(B_{ij}+B_{ij})S^{ij}$ and swap around some indices ;)